# Android Keystore from APK

Tags: android, android-keystore

Is there anyway to get the keystore file from .apk, Unfortunately the keystore file is missed now i need to update my app which is there is Google Play.
Please help, Thnx in advance

Comment: If that's possible then I would be snatching keystore files from popular apps!

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not. Imagine the huge security breach that would be. In addition to the already existing problem with code decompilation and recompilation, hackers could even sign a modified APK with the original key and pretend it to be original.